# Constant containing a instance of the declaring class

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do a Money class like this:

```
from __future__ import annotations;

class Money:
    __ZERO = Money(0)

    def __init__(self, amount: float):
        self.__amount: float = amount

    @staticmethod
    def ZERO() -> Money:
        return __ZERO

    @staticmethod
    def fromNumber(value: float) -> Money:
        return Money(value)
```

When I try to import money.py I have the following exception:

> name 'Money' is not defined
>
> File "E:\Desenvolvimento\Python\Money\money.py", line 4, in Money
>       __ONE = Money(0)
>
> File "E:\Desenvolvimento\Python\Money\money.py", line 3, in 
>       class Money:
>
> File "E:\Desenvolvimento\Python\Money\money_test.py", line 2, in 
>       from money import Money

I came from a Java background and after some reading I supposed this should work. Am I forgeting something or the approach to do this is completely different?

Comment: `Money` doesn't exist inside the class *definition*,  Python doesn't have class (or variable) declarations. Class and function definitions are executable code, they can go into loops or functions to dynamically create them. Both classes and functions are objects like any other in Python, so you can think of the definition statements as syntactic sugar for a call to the class object constructor, i.e. the three argument form of [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `__ZERO = Money(0)` the class `Money` isn't created yet, so you can't create an object of type `Money` yet, a workaround would be to define your class and then assign your constant later:

```
class Money:
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def fromNumber(value: float) -> 'Money':
    ...

Money.__ZERO = Money(0)

print(Money.__ZERO)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Money object at 0x7ff7c4016c50>
```

And, as suggested by @jonrsharpe, you can change the type annotation to `-> 'Money':`.

Comment: The return type annotation can be `-> 'Money'`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references

Comment: This may not actually work right due to name mangling. It might be better to have the `ZERO` method lazily initialize the `__ZERO` class attribute. Also, the annotation without the quotation marks can work if you use `from __future__ import annotations` in Python 3.7 (it will become allowed by default in Python 4 aka 3.10). See [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)!

Answer (score 1):

As MrGeek diagnosed in his answer, the problem you have is that the name `Money` doesn't exist yet when you're initializing your class variable. In Python, the class body all runs before the class object is created, and that happens before it can be bound in the outside namespace.

I suggest deferring the creation of the zero value until you first need to use it. Initialize it to some sentinel value (like `None`), and check if it's been set up yet when you want to use it:

```
class Money:
    __ZERO = None

    @staticmethod
    def ZERO():
        if Money.__ZERO is None:
            Money.__ZERO = Money(0)
        return Money.__ZERO
```

Note that you need to prefix all your uses of the attribute name with the class. There's no implicit access to class variables inside of methods in Python, you must be explicit. This might be a reason not to make `ZERO` a static method. If you make it a `classmethod`, you'd get the class passed in to the method as an argument:

```
    @classmethod
    def ZERO(cls):
        if cls.__ZERO is None:
            cls.__ZERO = cls(0)
        return cls.__ZERO
```

It's also not clear to me what the purpose of the `fromNumber` method is, since it's identical to the constructor of the class. Rather than calling `Money.fromNumber(x)`, you can always just call `Money(x)`.

A final note: You're currently using a double-underscore prefix for your constant class variable, and using a method to access it. Double leading underscores invokes Python's name mangling system, so the actual class variable is `_Money__ZERO` as far as any outside code would be concerned. This is not really intended to be like declaring a variable `private` in other languages. Instead, it's for when you don't want your attributes to accidentally collide with some unknown other variables (perhaps because you're a proxy object and don't know what methods and variables the object you're proxying will have).

For a normal class, it usually makes a lot more sense to either make an attribute a  part of your public API or to use a single underscore to indicate that it's intended to be private. There's no enforcement of that declaration, and Python will not try to protect it from outside access. But that's often a good thing for debugging and testing, where you want outside code to be able to poke around in your internals. So a more Pythonic approach might be:

```
class Money:
    def __init__(self, amount: float):
        self._amount: float = amount    # no need for name mangling here either
            # one underscore indicates the attribute is not part of your public API

Money.ZERO = Money(0) # set the class variable after defining the class
```

Then later code can directly fetch `Money.ZERO` when they want it, without needing to call any methods at all.

Comment: This is a "leaning Python" project where I am trying to recreate some implementatios done in the past. It is great to see some input like yours. The fromNumber method is a kind of factory method. There are other like fromString (don't know if it is really needed), fromCents and other uncommon things.

I still have some problems hoping that my private stuff keep private due to good faith  but i think it is just a cultural thing... :)

Comment: I suppose it's not harmful to try to data privacy, but it doesn't really work. Other code can in fact use the mangled name to get at your internal data if they really want to, the double underscores doesn't do anything to prevent it. But it does make writing a lot of normal code harder. For instance, the other answer's use of `__ZERO` outside of the class is actually setting a *different* class attribute than your in-class use touches. A `ZERO` staticmethod won't work with that kind of initialization.